Directly Driving a P-FET with STM8 MCU Without Using an N-FET: Is It Possible?
I'm working on a project where a customer has asked me to replicate a board that directly drives a P-FET using an STM8S MCU. Based on my knowledge, switching a P-FET usually requires an additional N-FET, and that's how I initially designed the circuit (circuit diagram attached).

However, the customer has raised concerns about the cost due to the production scale (between 10,000 to 100,000 units) and mentioned that their original product was able to control the P-FET directly from the STM8S without any additional FETs. They have asked me to modify my design to eliminate the two FETs.

Despite attempting to reverse-engineer the original board, I'm struggling to understand how this setup can operate without an N-FET.
For Example, I would like to mention the specific MOSFET model involved, the IRLML5203, which has a maximum gate-source threshold voltage (Vgs(th)) of -2.5V. Even if the MCU operates at a 5V level, the gate could potentially receive either 3.5V or 6V due to a division down from 7V or 12V supply voltages. Wouldn't both scenarios ensure that the FET remains on?
Am I missing something, or is it indeed possible to control a P-FET directly from an STM8 MCU? Any insights or similar experiences would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

P vs N is mostly a matter of on/off signal levels. If you can modify the program to go from active high to active low, I don't see what the problem is. If you can't modify the problem, then you'll need extra components indeed. (And of course the MCU needs to be able to sink an itty bit of current but that's unlikely a problem.)

You may be able to set the output pins on the STM8 to high impedance (say as input) to allow the gate to float high. However, there will almost certainly be a clamp diode which protects the GPIO which would probably mean that maximum voltage on the pin is limited to say 7 volts for a 5 volt device before the clamp cuts in. By adjusting the resistor values, you may just be able to get the Mosfet to switch cleanly off and on by setting the pin between high impedance and Output LOW respectively. For a commercial product, you should be sure that the data sheets of the components support this.

Have you considered load switch ICs? I'm sure there are cheap ones (at least, not too expensive than IRLML... PMOS) in SOT23-5 (or -6) packages. Almost all of them can be driven with voltages as low as 1.8V.

@Lundin It is a just software matter as long as there is not voltage translation to make. But the PFET seems to be tied to +12V according to the schematic, so purely software tricks won't be able to help here.

You could also replace the R10 in your final diagram with a 7v zener diode but such a solution is dependent on the supply voltage not changing too much from the stated 12v. With a 5v MCU, you may just get away with it.

Can you show the circuit of the previous model? It is not possible to drive the P-FET directly as shown. Q6/Q7 could be an extremely cheap bipolar transistor (1 cent) if it helps.

Thanks Everyone for detailed comment
I will study more with your comments,
Thanks again Everyone, Hope you all get happy day :)

The only way I can see this working is if the output board 12v supply is floating. Then you could connect the MCU supply to the +12v and drive the P FETs directly.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks, I'll test some more with your answer
